Analytic vs. Formal definition of integral on manifolds
In multivariable analysis or measure theory we learn how to integrate subsets of higher dimensional euclidean space, thus obtaining the 'right' notion of volume. In more algebraic setting when we study manifolds, we define the integral as the integral of a differential form. For example if you have a parameterization of a curve, we can calculate it's length by usual approximations. Similarly, using a 1 form, we can define a section to the cotangent bundle and then integrating it, supposedly we'll obtain the same length. Why are we allowed to move so freely between these 'different' versions of integral, and yet obtain the same result? Is there a theorem that makes this conversion precise?

Excuse me, but it is not clear to me what are you calling different versions of integration. The integration theory of differential forms over smooth manifolds is a generalization of the integration over Euclidean spaces, so it reduces to it when the manifold under consideration is an Euclidean space.

The first theorem that comes to mind is integration by substitution.

@Albert For example, if I embed the torus $T=S^1\times S^1$ in Euclidean space (in the usual way) and then define a smooth curve $(a,b)\rightarrow T$, then how does selecting and integrating a section to the tangent bundle restricted to the curve give its notion of length (as in the Euclidean space by using analytic approximations)?

@Tanizaki, every smooth manifold $M$ (such as the torus) admits a Riemannian metric $g$, and as such allows for a definition of length $\mathcal{l}$ of a curve $\gamma:(a,b)\to M$ given by
$$
\mathcal{l}[\gamma] = \int_a^b\sqrt{g_{\gamma(t)}(\gamma'(t), \gamma'(t))}dt
$$
which, in the case where $M = \mathbb{R}^n$ for $n\in\mathbb{N}$, reduces to the usual arc length in Euclidean space. That this real integral can be identified with the integral of a 1-form is precisely due by construction, and how integration of differential forms is defined by means of charts.

@Albert Thanks! I am not acquinted with the Riemannian metric so wasn't aware it accomplishes solving this problem.

See also this answer of mine on PhySE for some remarks on ‘correct things to integrate’.
